# Connect to cloudSQL db using service account with pymysql or mysql.connector

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, mysql-connector, pymysql

I have a running CloudSQL instance running in another VPC and a nginx proxy to allow cross-vpc access.
I can access the db using a built-in user. But how can I access the DB using a Google Service Account?

```
import google.auth
import google.auth.transport.requests
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import Error
import os

creds, project = google.auth.default()
auth_req = google.auth.transport.requests.Request()
creds.refresh(auth_req)


connection = mysql.connector.connect(host=HOST,
                                     database=DB,
                                     user=SA_USER,
                                     password=creds.token)
if connection.is_connected():
    db_Info = connection.get_server_info()
    print("Connected to MySQL Server version ", db_Info)
    cur = connection.cursor()
    cur.execute("""SELECT now()""")
    query_results = cur.fetchall()
    print(query_results)
```

When using mysql connnector, I get this error:

```
DatabaseError: 2059 (HY000): Authentication plugin 'mysql_clear_password' cannot be loaded: plugin not enabled
```

Then I tried using pymysql

```
import pymysql
import google.auth
import google.auth.transport.requests
import os

creds, project = google.auth.default()
auth_req = google.auth.transport.requests.Request()
creds.refresh(auth_req)


try:
    conn =  pymysql.connect(host=ENDPOINT, user=SA_USER, passwd=creds.token, port=PORT, database=DBNAME)
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("""SELECT now()""")
    query_results = cur.fetchall()
    print(query_results)
except Exception as e:
    print("Database connection failed due to {}".format(e))
```

```
Database connection failed due to (1045, "Access denied for user 'xx'@'xxx.xxx.xx.xx' (using password: YES)"
```

I guess these errors are all related to the token.
Anyone to suggest a proper way to get SA token to access CloudSQL DB?

**PS: Using cloudsql auth proxy is not a good option for our architecture.**

Comment: Max, let me knwo if below information was helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It finally works.
I had to enforce SSL connection.

```
import pymysql
from google.oauth2 import service_account
import google.auth.transport.requests

scopes = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/sqlservice.admin"] 
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file('key.json', scopes=scopes)
auth_req = google.auth.transport.requests.Request()
credentials.refresh(auth_req)
config = {'user': SA_USER,
            'host': ENDPOINT,
            'database': DBNAME,
            'password': credentials.token,
            'ssl_ca': './server-ca.pem',
            'ssl_cert': './client-cert.pem',
            'ssl_key': './client-key.pem'}
try:
    conn =  pymysql.connect(**config)
    with conn:
        print("Connected")
        cur = conn.cursor()
        cur.execute("""SELECT now()""")
        query_results = cur.fetchall()
        print(query_results)
except Exception as e:
    print("Database connection failed due to {}".format(e))
```

Answer (score 0):

The error that you have mentioned in description , indicates an issue with authentication , to exactly understand what could have caused ,[try these things](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/debugging-connectivity#connection_issues_checklist)

- Verify the username and corresponding password.
- Check the origin of the connection to see if it matches the URL where
  the user has access privileges.
- Check the user's grant privileges in the database.

As you are trying to access the DB using a Google Service Account then you should try to use the default service account credentials to include this authorization token for you. Check out the [Client libraries and sample code](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-python-connector/blob/main/README.md#iam-authentication) page for more info.Alternatively, if you prefer to manually create the requests, you can use an Oauth 2.0 token. The [Authorizing requests](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/admin-api/how-tos/authorizing) page has more information for how to create these.These access tokens are only valid for 60 minutes after which they expire - however once a token expires it does not disconnect clients but if that client connection is broken and must re-connect to the instance, and it's been more than an hour, then a new access token will need to be pulled and provided on that new connection attempt.
For your use case as you are not interested in cloud sql proxy, a service account IAM user is the better way to go.
Note that to get an appropriate access token the scope must be set to [Cloud SQL Admin API](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/scopes#sqladmin).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions @Vaidehi Jamankar . Sorry for the late reply. I will give it a try and get back to you. 
Using a Oauth token for the service account should be ok.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using the [Cloud SQL Python Connector](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-python-connector) it should make your life way easier!

It manages the SSL connection for you (no need for cert files!), takes care of the credentials (uses [Application Default Credentials](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/application-default-credentials) which you can set to service account easily) and allows you to login with [Automatic IAM AuthN](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/authentication#automatic) so that you don't have to pass the credentials token as a password.

Connecting looks like this:

```py
from google.cloud.sql.connector import Connector, IPTypes
import sqlalchemy
import pymysql

# initialize Connector object
connector = Connector(ip_type=IPTypes.PRIVATE, enable_iam_auth=True,)

# function to return the database connection
def getconn() -> pymysql.connections.Connection:
    conn: pymysql.connections.Connection = connector.connect(
        "project:region:instance",  # your Cloud SQL instance connection name
        "pymysql",
        user="my-user",
        db="my-db-name"
    )
    return conn

# create connection pool
pool = sqlalchemy.create_engine(
    "mysql+pymysql://",
    creator=getconn,
)

# insert statement
insert_stmt = sqlalchemy.text(
    "INSERT INTO my_table (id, title) VALUES (:id, :title)",
)

# interact with Cloud SQL database using connection pool
with pool.connect() as db_conn:
    # insert into database
    db_conn.execute(insert_stmt, id="book1", title="Book One")

    # query database
    result = db_conn.execute("SELECT * from my_table").fetchall()

    # Do something with the results
    for row in result:
        print(row)
```

Let me know if you run into any issues! There is also an [interactive Cloud SQL Notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/github/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-python-connector/blob/main/samples/notebooks/mysql_python_connector.ipynb) that will walk your through things in more detail you can check out.

Comment: We are not using this solution because we need to have a cross-vpc access. And we are making use of a shared VPC and an Nginx proxy placed in the shared VPC to make it work.